# How was the boat murder performed?

Tags: plot-explanation, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

In Quentin Tarantino’s latest film *Once Upon a Time in Hollywood*, in a flashback, we see

> Brad Pitt’s character on a boat with his wife, with a snorkel mask, some kind of long pipe or gun, and some sort of pressurized can.

From the context and dialogue it’s clear that these items are used to bring about a death in some fashion (for which that character is not caught), but the details are not revealed.

What are these items exactly, and how were they (most likely) used to accomplish this murder in the film’s universe?

Answer (score 10):

> What are these items exactly

It's a harpoon/speargun

> How were they (most likely) used to accomplish this murder in the film’s universe?

The details, as you say, are not shown but it's implied that Cliff shoots his wife with 
the weapon either by accident (because the boat lurches) or deliberately.

[**Esquire.com**](https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/movies/a28783888/once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood-brad-pitt-cliff-booth-boat-kill-wife-death/)

> The film presents the question in a brief flashback, where Cliff is drunk on a boat, holding a harpoon being egged on by his wife. The boat lurches forward and it's implied that Cliff either accidentally or purposefully shot his nagging wife.